# Avoid code repetition - reactJs - javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refactoring

All the time in my app I'm repeating code like this:

```
if (prodStatus !== Product.Sold) {
  this.setState({isSold: false});
} else {
  this.setState({isStillThere: false});
}
```

I've repeated it in my component at least 10x, could I somehow refactor it to looks more nicer or something like that?

Thanks guys

Cheers

Comment: Without knowing how your component uses that it is hard to give a definitive answer. Also where does `prodStatus` come from? Maybe it could be refactored to use `useReducer` or maybe a simple function could be sufficient. But at least 10 times in a single component already seems suspicious to me. Also what is the semantic difference of `isSold = true` and `isStillThere = false`?

Comment: Custom hooks may help. 
Here there is a useBoolean hook.
https://daveceddia.com/custom-hooks/

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, you could just use 
`this.setState({isSold: prodStatus === Product.Sold})`

And then instead of checking `this.state.isStillThere` in your code, just check `!this.state.isSold`.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up) in the React Tutorial, they showcase an example situation similar to what you are dealing with, namely, state that needs to be visible for sub-components but shouldn't be repeated.

They pass the desired property into the `props` of the sub-component, which is what is generally done (in my experience) with properties that need to be passed down.

Here is some example code:

```
import React from 'react';
import SubComponent from 'SubComponent';

// MainComponent has prodStatus in props or state.
export default class MainComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div><SubComponent prodStatus={this.state.prodStatus} /></div>;
  }
}
```

Or if you prefer the function syntax (I am not familiar so please let me know if I made a mistake):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import SubComponent from 'SubComponent';

// MainComponent has prodStatus in props or state.
export default function MainComponent(props) {
  const [prodStatus, setProdStatus] = useState(/*prodStatus code*/);
  return <div><SubComponent prodStatus={prodStatus} /></div>;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use ternary operator

```
    prodStatus !== Product.Sold ?
 this.setState({ isSold: false }) :
 this.setState({ isStillThere: false })
```

Further refference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator